# Is it possible to test for causality using Bayes theorem and frequency tables?

Tags: bayesian, causality, frequency

I am used to test causality using Granger test with time series. But I don't know how to test for causality with categorical data. For instance, I want to test if a high level of hardskill causes a high level of softskills (or is it the way around ; softskills causing hardskills). The following frequency table shows row percentages in red and column percentages in black.

[image]

We can see that 86% of people with high hardskills also show a high level of softskills, but only 30% of people with high softskills have a high level of hardskills.

So intuitively one is tempted to admit that hardskills cause softskills, and not the other way around. But I don't think that's a sufficient statistical evidence. So I was wondering if Bayes theorem can be used in this case ? Because the way I see it, this translates to :

P(S|H) = 86%

P(H|S) = 30%

With

H : having a high level of hardskills

S : having a high level of softskills

But I also realize this is too simple to be true. Can someone please help me and tell me if I am making a mistake (and where, if I am) ? Also, is there a way to test for causality in my case with categorical data ?

Thanks,

Comment: What is your hypothesis? To establish a causal effect an important part is to rule out potential confounding. That's not something you seem to be doing yet.